# Is it possible to sense a temperature using an infrared LED?

Tags: infrared, transmitter, receiver

Is it possible to make a remote thermometer using a standard IR LED as a transmitter and an IR receiver diode as a receiver?

The range is about 5 meters. I know there are chips available for this purpose but I’d like to understand the principle.

Do the temperature sensor chips use only receiving diodes?

How is it done in thermo-vision hunting cameras so it is able to sense over 1km?

Comment: what function would the LED serve?

Comment: @jsotola I thought about increasing the reflection from object surface so it would be easier to sense. :)

Comment: the object emits IR .... that is what's being measured

Answer (score 3):

No, IR photodiodes are only sensitive to near-infrared light. To measure temperature, you need to measure far-infrared energy, then use blackbody radiation equations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_thermometer

Comment: Oh. I see. The receiver has to catch the wide wavelength range.

Comment: Depends on the temperature that you're attempting to sense. A microwave radio receiver can sense temperature. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background

Comment: @DDuck Thank you. That’s interesting.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Near IR LEDs can be used (though you'd prefer photodiodes) if the temperature you are looking at is high enough. Say 400 C or higher, just as a guess. I've done it with a narrow band around 860nm. But this brings up another point. Wide band isn't good. To use the BB radiation curve you want a very narrow slice. And you also need to know the average emissivity over the target view. That's shape-dependent as well as material (though it's basically 1 inside an integrating sphere in all cases.)